# MySQL FOREIGN KEY Constraints Syntax

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pay_grade_scale` FOREIGN KEY `pay_scale_id` REFERENCES `pay_s`' at line 11

What is the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pay_grades` (
    `pay_grade_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `pay_scale_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `basic_salary` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,  
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
   PRIMARY KEY (`pay_grade_id`),
   INDEX (`pay_scale_id`, `pay_grade_id`),  
   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pay_grade_scale` FOREIGN KEY `pay_scale_id` REFERENCES `pay_scales`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pay_scales` (
`id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use **`ADD CONSTRAINT`** in a **`CREATE TABLE`** declaration.
Declare your constraint after creating the table or in the **`CREATE TABLE`**.

---

**First solution: Add the constraint in CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pay_grades` (
  `pay_grade_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `pay_scale_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `basic_salary` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,  
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
   PRIMARY KEY (`pay_grade_id`),
   INDEX (`pay_scale_id`, `pay_grade_id`),  
   FOREIGN KEY (`pay_scale_id`) REFERENCES `pay_scales`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

**Second solution: Alter table to add the constraint**

Create your table without the constraint, and then add your constraint as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE `pay_grades` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `pay_scale_id` FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `pay_scales`(`id`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for foreign keys declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the difference in order of table creation. First create primary key table than create the table of foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pay_scales` (
`id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pay_grades` (
    `pay_grade_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `pay_scale_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `basic_salary` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,  
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
   PRIMARY KEY (`pay_grade_id`),
   INDEX (`pay_scale_id`, `pay_grade_id`),  
   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pay_grade_scale` FOREIGN KEY `pay_scale_id` REFERENCES `pay_scales`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```